# Is this sum equivalence done right?

Tags: analysis, power-series

Is 
$$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{k}k}{k!} = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \frac{t^{k}}{(k-1)!} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{k+1}}{(k)!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{k}t}{(k)!}
= e^t t$$
a valid equivalence?

Comment: changing tags from `riemann-sum` to `analysis` and `power-series`.

Comment: You did well. Just note the index starting $k=0$ in the first and $k=1$ in second equality.

Comment: (0-1)! ist not defined, so it has to start with k = 1 right?

Comment: The case $k=0$ in the first equality is redundant, because $\frac{t^kk}{k!}=0$ for $k=0$, thus has no affect on the sum. Thus it's valid to start with $k=1$.

Comment: ok thank you very much.